# R : Histogram adjust frequency scale representation

Tags: r, scale, histogram, frequency

This may be something very trivial, but since I don't have much experience in R, I may be missing something. Basically, my frequency values being large are being represented in exponents on y axis[image]-

Here are the counts

```
# $counts
#  [1] 374850  81009  56419  45259  35765  29697  25637  23587  21461  19418  18221  17094  15902  15098  13874  13257
# [17]  12602  11883  10974  10427   9553   9213   8278   7975   7325   6904   6641   5989   5467   4684   4253   3704
# [33]   3355   2918   2722   2427   2301   2178   1909   1786   1657   1462   1346   1178   1061    900    745    651
# [49]    437    316    214     63
```

I understand, it is rather a very wide range. Is there a way I can compress the scale and still have values that make sense e.g in K(thousands) or M(millions)?

Comment: Do you want to disable scientific notation?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by first disabling the axis in your hist call, then by adding in the axis again with the help of axTicks.

```
# generate some data
x <- rchisq(1000000,df=1)

# create histogram
x.hist <- hist(x,breaks=7,axes=FALSE)

# create new axis

# draw axis along 'y' axTicks(2) gets the values along 'x' from your plot
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), labels=paste(axTicks(2)/1000000,"mil",sep=""))

# draw axis along 'x' axTicks(1) gets the values along 'x' from your plot
axis(1, at=axTicks(1), labels=paste( axTicks(1) ," hats",sep=""))
```

And you get something that looks like this,

[image]

Comment: This works great Jonathan. Thank you! on a side note - if you notice in my post, the y axis does not cover maximum frequency, can you comment on why that might be happening ?

Comment: if you set ylim within hist you could set the max value on the frequency.
e.g. 
    hist(x,axes=FALSE,ylim=(0,200000))

Comment: Thanks. I understand it much better now.